# How do I link data from two separate programs into one?

Tags: c++

I have two programs

```
main.cpp

// initialization of the array only here!
int numbers[4] = {1,2,3,4};

int main()
{

std::cout << numbers[3] << std::endl;

return 0;
};
```

and the second program that has no initialization of the array, but I would like to call it

```
main2.cpp
// now this program doesn't know what array numbers is
int main()
{

std::cout << numbers[3] << std::endl;

return 0;
};
```

I run the program first `main.cpp` and then I can run the program `main2.cpp` I'm wondering if I can get data from the first program and connect it to another program.

This should be done as quickly as possible, so that the program under the number `main2.cpp` read and use the data as if it were part of it.

Comment: Why not get the second program to read the output of the first by using `std::cin` and a command line like `main | main2`. There is no simple way to share your array between the two processes. There is more information here  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279128/how-to-share-memory-between-applications-written-in-c-c

Comment: You can't do that - there is no connection between the two processes and they don't share memory. You need to transfer the data from one process to the other.

Comment: @DNT I think this will work slowly just like writing data to a file and reading it

Comment: @Anton OK, in that case I suggest you look into using shared memory. Check the link I posted.

Comment: @molbdnilo I could allocate memory for the second program if the data transfer itself is fast.

Comment: If you run ```main.cpp``` first and then ```main2.cpp``` one way is to call main2 binary from within ```main.cpp``` and pass the array as an argument. Won't work with very large arrays or complex datatypes, but for your example, should be fine.

Comment: @Roy2511 everything that is called once will not work, I'm not just doing lessons for the exam. I need this program, I want to perform different interactions between programs. a kind of OOP only each program is separate.

I have two ideas now, 1) use shared memory and 2) implement everything via socket

Comment: unfortunately, both examples make the program more complex, it is possible that in C++20 there is something simpler, which I do not know

Answer (score 0):

The main functions that run two CPPs belong to different processes. In C++, the variables of different processes are private and cannot be shared.